# I want to join two DataFrames with filling NaN in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, data-science, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two dataframe in pyspark in the following manner
df1 looks like:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+                 
|         id|      date_start_id|      date_end_id|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
|          1|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          2|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          3|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          4|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          5|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          6|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          7|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          8|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|          9|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
|         10|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

And df2 looks like:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+                 
|         id|      date_start_id|      date_end_id|   response|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
|          2|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          3|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          5|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          7|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          8|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

I want to join both the dataframes in such a way so that it looks like:

```
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+                 
|         id|      date_start_id|      date_end_id|   response|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
|          1|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|       null|
|          2|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          3|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          4|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|       null|
|          5|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          6|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|       null|
|          7|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          8|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|          1|
|          9|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|       null|
|         10|         2019-01-29|       2019-02-09|       null|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------+
```

What i did:

```
df = df1.join(df2, ["id","date_start_id","date_end_id"], "left")
```

But, unfortunately this didn't worked for me. Any kind of help or hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you miss some other thing. For me the join produces the exact result that you desired, but unordered. You can solve this by ordering by id for example.
Can you maybe explain why it didn't work out for you? Did you get an error or a different result?

Comment: yeah!! actually there are few duplicate columns which are creating issue, now the issue is resolved. Thanks for viewing my question.

Answer (score 0):

#Pyspark Take NaN as a value, So insert NaN after join. and I use SQL more with spark because it is fast.

```
     def dropColumn_sql(df,col_names,spark):
         col_names = [item for item in df.columns if item not in col_names]
         df = df.selectExpr(col_names)
         return df
def join_df_with_NaN(df1, df2, cond, how):
    df = df1.join(df2, cond, how=how) 
    for col in df.columns:
        df = df.selectExpr("*", f""" case when {col} == null then cast('nan' as float) else {col} end as {col+'_temp'}""")
        li = []
        li.append(col)
        df = dropColumn_sql(df, li, spark).withColumnRenamed(col+'_temp', col )
    return df
```